# iOS - Create NSDate without hours/minutes and ignoring daylight saving shifts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to remove hours and minutes from my `NSDate` object

```
keyDate = [[array objectAtIndex:i] date];
unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:flags fromDate:keyDate];
keyDate = [[calendar dateFromComponents:components] dateByAddingTimeInterval:[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]secondsFromGMT]];
```

and it works fine until April 2013, after that my `NSDate` objects are created with -1 hour shift. I'm pretty sure it is because daylight saving time.

How can I make my `NSDate` objects be 00:00:00 +0000 during all year ?

Comment: `NSDate` is meant to ALWAYS be GMT-based. Why do you want to add the difference to the local timezone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSDate` objects are inherently stored as GMT values.   The problem you're running into here is that you're doing calculations using the currentCalendar (which might be in DST at the moment) and the localTimeZone secondsFromGMT, which switches depending on the time of year.

The best solution here is to use an NSCalendar that is GMT instead of based on a timezone that shifts, if (as you indicate) you want them to be +0000 at all times.

Alternatively, you can change to use `NSTimeZone`'s `secondsFromGMTForDate:` which takes into account DST at the date/time in question.

Comment: Could you please update your answer with some code? Thank you!

Comment: @Oleg - You really can't find the part where you are adding the TimeZone offset?

Comment: I don't really understand what should I do with my NSCalendar object

Comment: @Oleg, the smallest change would be to replace your call to `secondsFromGMT` with the call to `secondsFromGMTForDate: keyDate`

Comment: Oh, that was so simple! Thank you! :-)

Comment: @gaige Thank  you, the simplest, most straight forward and life saving answer i found on this topic.